# Ensure that multiple requests are processed one after the other

Tags: php, mysql, queue

**To explain what actually happens:**

An external service sends a HTTP POST request with XML data to a PHP script. This script checks if the data already exists in the MySQL DB. If not, it inserts a new record.

Now there came a second service for failure safety. It sends the exact same XML data to the PHP script.

**The Problem:**

The script already checks if the record exists. But the requests are coming nearly at the same time and the script gets called in parallel. So the data of both requests with the same data are getting inserted.

I thought about using a queue but I can't imagine a simple way to do this. This whole process is actually very simple.

What's the easiest way to ensure to not insert data twice?

Comment: Use unique keys, and INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE form of the Insert statement. With http requests, there is no way to ensure the order received.

Comment: Use transactions.

Comment: I don't think transaction would change anything but unique keys would - I think. I'll try to clean up the DB and add UNIQUE keys.

Answer (score 0):

generate a hash for your transaction, make it unique at the DB level. MySQL will throw if you try to add the same data twice ?